# What is the purpose of this pad

Tags: emc, high-frequency, high-speed, emi-filtering

What is the purpose of this pad, located between the PCB in the picture and a wifi card?

It is completely enclosed in Kapton tape and there are no exposed grounds on the PCB below, on the bottom of the wifi card there are passives, nothing else. The mesh is conductive and wraps around both sides of the pad, i.e. there is a connection between the top and the bottom of the pad.

I do not think it is for thermal management and I do not see an issue with cavity resonance at these frequencies.

[image: Picture of a pad on a PCB]

Comment: Not tied to ground? Odd. Otherwise it would seem to be a typical rf shield.

Comment: Nope! No path to ground or anything else! I think this would make EMI issues worse as it will just couple to the wifi card (not the wifi itself but PCIe traces, etc) and then radiate it out. There are many other issues with this board so might just be done in error?

Comment: Can't even imagine that it would pass UL testing if that was the case. Most companies don't want to get on the FCCs bad side.

Comment: Even if the conductive shield isn't DC-grounded, it will act as a big capacitor between nearby traces. I'm guessing it's an "oh sh!t" fix added when they found the WiFi card didn't meet a noise figure spec when receiving, and it was too late to redesign the motherboard.